is keybert dependent on scipy?
from keybert import KeyBERT

doc = """
         Supervised learning is the machine learning task of learning a function that
         maps an input to an output based on example input-output pairs. It infers a
         function from labeled training data consisting of a set of training examples.
         In supervised learning, each example is a pair consisting of an input object
         (typically a vector) and a desired output value (also called the supervisory signal).
         A supervised learning algorithm analyzes the training data and produces an inferred function,
         which can be used for mapping new examples. An optimal scenario will allow for the
         algorithm to correctly determine the class labels for unseen instances. This requires
         the learning algorithm to generalize from the training data to unseen situations in a
         'reasonable' way (see inductive bias).
      """
 kw_model = KeyBERT()
 kw_model.extract_keywords(doc, keyphrase_ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words=None)
 [('learning algorithm', 0.6978),
  ('machine learning', 0.6305),
  ('supervised learning', 0.5985),
  ('algorithm analyzes', 0.5860),
  ('learning function', 0.5850)]

i want to extract the keywords from the text but im encountering this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Ravikiran\Projects\IIMSTC tech\Sprint 2\keyber.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keybert import KeyBERT
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\keybert\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keybert._model import KeyBERT
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\keybert\_model.py", line 9, in <module>
    from sklearn import __version__ as sklearn_version
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .utils._estimator_html_repr import _HTMLDocumentationLinkMixin, estimator_html_repr
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._chunking import gen_batches, gen_even_slices
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_chunking.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._param_validation import Interval, validate_params
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_param_validation.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .validation import _is_arraylike_not_scalar
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ..utils._array_api import _asarray_with_order, _is_numpy_namespace, get_namespace
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_array_api.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .fixes import parse_version
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 20, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 606, in <module>
    from ._stats_py import *
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_py.py", line 49, in <module>
    from . import distributions
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _continuous_distns
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_continuous_distns.py", line 33, in <module>
    import scipy.stats._boost as _boost
  File "C:\Users\hravi\anaconda3\envs\sprint2env\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_boost\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from scipy.stats._boost.nct_ufunc import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.stats._boost.nct_ufunc'


The traceback shows that it does, but I'm not sure how that'll help you. Scipy should automatically be installed, if you're trying to ask if you need to install it. But maybe you can pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall scipy

Do you have a virus scanner which quarantined the nct_ufunc file? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78445257/530160

Thanks for your answer and the actual problem here was McAfee detecting the nct_ufunc file and i have removed it from being scanned for further. It solved my error and working fine.
